# How to crop and rotate an image in pdf file in Java?

Tags: java, image, pdf, crop, rotatetransform

In Java, I have to crop and rotate an image in scanned pdf file and create another pdf file with the result image
For example, I have the image1 and want get the image2 centered in the page as result

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

How can I proceed?

Thanks!

The pdf is a scanned file.
It contains for example a student card.
I have to rotate the stutend card scanned on the right way and centered it in the A4 page.

I try to get the image like this :

```
PDDocument docIn = null;
File inputPdfFile = new File("C:\\test.pdf");
File output = new File("C:\\testOutput.png");

try {
    // Read the pdf into a BufferedImage
    docIn = PDDocument.load(inputPdfFile);
    List<PDPage> pages = docIn.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
    PDPage page = pages.get(0);

    // get the image
    BufferedImage image = page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 300);
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", output);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then, I use the javaxt librairies to trim the image

```
Image image = new Image(output);
image.trim();
image.saveAs("C:\\projetCrop\\trimImage.png");
```

Now, how to detect the rotation angle?

Comment: There is no simple answer. What libraries do you use? What have you tried?

Comment: Please consider edit the question and add some code.

Comment: First of all, I'd like to know how to get the first picture on the right way (to the 2nd picture)?
And then I will be able to choose the librairies
I didn't develop yet because I haven't the slightest idea how to do it? I'm lost.

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of ways to do it. What you're describing requires a library that lets you manipulate individual objects on a page in a PDF file. You'll have to be able to rotate and translate them. Surely that gives you enough information to at least start looking for a library that has these capabilities? What is it that stops you from starting to look? (otherwise said and perhaps less nicely, put in some effort yourself if you expect to get quality answers...)

Comment: By your images do you mean that the original image is a *bitmap* image inserted into the original PDF *rotated* somewhat oddly and you want to insert it at a different angle? Or could it be *any image* (bitmap or vector) and the crop area is at such an odd angle in that image?

Comment: I begin development, add some code